# How to delete a specific word in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

i need to ask if you there is something in excel where you can find a specific word in a cell and delete that but keep the other words or character in place.  For example if I just want to delete dog in a cell.  But the dog can be found in a middle of the word, at the end or the beginning. I just want to find that word and delete that

Comment: Press Ctrl+H » Search for `Dog` » Replace with nothing

Answer (score 3):

Press Ctrl+F and select the replace tab. This will find and replace words in the document.

Find Replace Window shown here:

[image]

Comment: Pro tip: CTRL + H goes directly to the Replace tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SUBSTITUTE formula.

If your text is in column A, then you can type this in B1 and drag or copy

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"DOG","")
```

The above formula will substitute the word DOG with a blank.